# Excel Vlookup returns NA

Tags: excel, vlookup

I use macro to record a live data every 5 second, and also a table with minute time column and corresponding values for lookup. I used regular vlookup with 4th argument as True, but only getting #N/A. Any tips to how to lookup with time?

```
=VLOOKUP(B8, Data!$A$1:$B$599, 2, TRUE)
```

B8 is the time in Time column in first table, Data!$A$1:$B$599 is the lookup table

```
Time        Data to Match
07:41:50   
07:42:00    
07:42:18    
07:42:57    
07:43:07        
07:43:17
```

Lookup table:

```
07:39:00    0.000373257
07:40:00    0.000490657
07:41:00    0.000283575
07:42:00    0.000318266
07:43:00    0.000409149
07:44:00    0.000311742
07:45:00    0.000331792
07:46:00    0.000343248
07:47:00    0.000382561
```

I just want to fill in the Data to Match column with corresponding values in the lookup table, rounding up or down are both fine, approximate match.

Comment: can you post a representative sample of your data and layout of that data?

Comment: You might need to sort the data, for VLOOKUP, the data needs to be in ASCENDANT way.

Comment: For more on what @sous2817 is talking about read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've updated the data. Both time and lookup table are sorted already

Comment: What is the vlookup you are trying?

Comment: are you using `TRUE` as your last argument in the vlookup?

Comment: I get no errors with my VLOOKUP,  Please post the formula you are using, you probably have a typo in the formula itself.

Comment: If the data is as you show then the formula should work.  I would look at the data.  One may be text that looks like a time and the other time.  Or some other data mishap, like unprintable characters.

Comment: Are the values in each time column right aligned or left aligned? Did you manually adjust the alignment? If not right-aligned then one or both of the columns are text.
 - Did you format the time values? Check the raw value in the formula bar to determine that one or both time columns does not include a date.

Comment: Agreed, must be some data format issue, couldn't quite figure out with formatting cells. INDEX MATCH worked fine however. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of cases I prefer using INDEX/MATCH.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$9;MATCH($E1;$A$1:$A$9;1))
```

Where:

B1:B9 = Range of the data you want to return

E1 = Value to compare with the index

A1:A9 = List of times where you want to match a result

The last "1" argument is to find the nearest lowest result, the list will have to be in ASCENDANT way for this.